# Getting java.lang.classcastexception on Android during startup

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest, classcastexception

I have written a simple app, that to begin with, only contained an single Activity and multiple other classes (not inheriting from Activity). I have now added a new class, HandlePrefs, that also inherits from Activity and added a new  tag in the manifest file matching this class.

Now I get and java.lang.classcastexception error during startup (but only when using API lvl 15 and above. It works just fine on older API versions.

This is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="tal.game.ammelampe.classes"
  android:versionCode="3"
  android:versionName="1.2"
  android:installLocation="preferExternal">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
             android:label="Amme Lampe lite" 
             android:allowBackup="true">


    <provider android:name=".FeedingProvider"
              android:authorities="tal.game.ammelampe.FeedingProvider" />        

    <activity android:name="tal.game.ammelampe.classes.AmmeLampeApp"
              android:label="Amme Lampe Lite"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="tal.game.ammelampe.classes.HandlePrefs">
    </activity>
 </application> 

 </manifest>
```

This is my AndroidApp class (the startup class)

```
package tal.game.framework.impl;


import tal.game.ammelampe.classes.HelpScreen;
import tal.game.ammelampe.classes.MainMenuScreen;
import tal.game.ammelampe.classes.Settings;
import tal.game.framework.App;
import tal.game.framework.FileIO;
import tal.game.framework.Graphics;
import tal.game.framework.Input;
import tal.game.framework.Screen;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
//import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;


public abstract class AndroidApp extends Activity implements App {
    AndroidFastRenderView renderView;
    Graphics graphics;
    Input input;
    FileIO fileIO;
    Screen screen;
    WakeLock wakeLock;
    public static Vibrator v;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Debug.startMethodTracing();
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        boolean isLandscape = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        int frameBufferWidth = isLandscape ? 480 : 320;
        int frameBufferHeight = isLandscape ? 320 : 480;
        Bitmap frameBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameBufferWidth,
                frameBufferHeight, Config.RGB_565);

        float scaleX = (float) frameBufferWidth   /   getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(); 
        float scaleY = (float) frameBufferHeight  / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        renderView = new AndroidFastRenderView(this, frameBuffer);
        graphics = new AndroidGraphics(getAssets(), frameBuffer);
        fileIO = new AndroidFileIO(getAssets());

        input = new AndroidInput(this, renderView, scaleX, scaleY);
        screen = getStartScreen();
        setContentView(renderView);

        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)     getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "GLGame");


    }
```

the new class that also inherits from Activity:

```
package tal.game.ammelampe.classes;


import tal.game.ammelampe.classes.FeedingDBMetaData.FeedingTableMetaData;
import tal.game.framework.App;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;



public class HandlePrefs extends Activity{


// Definer keys i preferences
    private static final String INITIALIZED = "initialized"; 
    private static final String name      = "name";
private static final String dob       = "dob";
private static final String sex       = "sex";
private static final String bgColor   = "bgcolor";
private static final String onOffLamp = "onofflamp";




// This variable is set in the LoadingScreen class
public static Long currentDate;
public static Long LongDob;



public static String lName = "";            
public static String lDob;                  
public static String lSex;                  
public static String lBgColor;              
public static String lOnOffLamp;            





static SharedPreferences myPrefs;
Activity activity = this;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 }
```

A lot of the code in class is not included above as i'm confident it is not causing the error. But in case i'm wrong i'll of course supply you guys with it :)

And finally the LogCat output:

```
03-19 21:51:49.201: W/dalvikvm(3256): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ab4228)
03-19 21:51:49.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3256): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 21:51:49.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3256): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tal.game.ammelampe.classes/tal.game.ammelampe.classes.AmmeLampeApp}: java.lang.ClassCastException: tal.game.ammelampe.classes.AmmeLampeApp cannot be cast to android.app.Application
03-19 21:51:49.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
03-19 21:51:49.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
03-19 21:51:49.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
03-19 21:51:49.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
03-19 21:51:49.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-19 21:51:49.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
03-19 21:51:49.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
03-19 21:51:49.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 21:51:49.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-19 21:51:49.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-19 21:51:49.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-19 21:51:49.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 21:51:49.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3256): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: tal.game.ammelampe.classes.AmmeLampeApp cannot be cast to android.app.Application
03-19 21:51:49.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.view.Window.getCompatInfo(Window.java:475)
03-19 21:51:49.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.<init>(Window.java:485)
03-19 21:51:49.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.view.Window.setWindowManager(Window.java:471)
03-19 21:51:49.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.app.Activity.attach(Activity.java:4517)
03-19 21:51:49.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
03-19 21:51:49.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3256):     ... 11 more
03-19 21:51:49.281: E/EmbeddedLogger(185): App crashed! Process: tal.game.ammelampe.classes
03-19 21:51:49.281: E/EmbeddedLogger(185): App crashed! Package: tal.game.ammelampe.classes v3 (1.2)
03-19 21:51:49.281: E/EmbeddedLogger(185): App crashed! Application Label: Amme Lampe lite
03-19 21:51:49.281: W/ActivityManager(185):   Force finishing activity tal.game.ammelampe.classes/.AmmeLampeApp
```

I have tried modfifying the manifest file with the android:name="android.app.Application" tag as a direct child in the  tag (as suggested in other similar questions), but still getting the same error. What am I doing wrong here?

LogCat with the android:name="android.app.Application" tag in the manifest file:

```
03-19 22:00:19.789: E/AndroidRuntime(4154): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 22:00:19.789: E/AndroidRuntime(4154): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{tal.game.ammelampe.classes/tal.game.ammelampe.classes.AmmeLampeApp}:   java.lang.ClassCastException: tal.game.ammelampe.classes.AmmeLampeApp cannot be cast to android.app.Application
```

The App class:

```
package tal.game.framework;

import android.content.Context;

public interface App {
    public Input getInput();

    public FileIO getFileIO();

    public Graphics getGraphics();

    public void setScreen(Screen screen);

    public Screen getCurrentScreen();

    public Screen getStartScreen();

    public Context getApplicationContext();
}
```

Comment: Why are you `implements App`?

Comment: App is just an interface (class) :)

Comment: I'm not sure that it matters but `getApplicationContext()` is also an abstract method in [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()) which Activity inherits.

Perhaps rename your method `getApplicationContext()` and your interface `App`; lets face it the nomenclature of your `App` class could be more descriptive.

Comment: Thanks so much! Renaming the getApplicationContext() method did the trick! :) I have also renamed the App interface, to a more descriptive one, for safety's sake. PS Sorry for the late follow-up, i have been on easterholiday...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement App instead just extend Activity like this

Change: `public abstract class AndroidApp extends Activity implements App {`

to: `public abstract class AndroidApp extends Activity {`

Comment: The App class is a class i have implemented myself, and is a part of the app framework :)

Comment: I think you would be well suited to rename the interface

Answer (score 0):

THe class Ammelameapp which you list as an Activity in the manifest doesn't derive from Activity.  Your AndroidApp class does derive from Activity, but its abstract (so it can't be used directly) and implements something called App which I have no idea what it is.  I think you need to read up on exactly what Activity and Application mean in Android.

Every app has an Application object.  You can use the Android default, or you can extend it and make your own.  Apps can have 1 or more Activities which are concrete classes and must extend from Activity.  Those Activities are listed in the manifest, inside of the application.  That listing includes the fully qualified path of the class or the .ClassName form for a local activity.

Comment: I have included the App class code above. The thing is that the manifest file is correct regarding this statement:
    <activity android:name="tal.game.ammelampe.classes.AmmeLampeApp"

I have now added the new class HandlePrefs (instead of writing the prefs in a text file on the SD card). This requires that the class extends Activity. So I have added the Activity tag in the manifest file and also included an OnCreate method in the class itself. Am I missing something else?

But im not sure why this is causing the classcastexception on API levels above 15...

Answer (score 0):

As JBirdVegas said in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510420/getting-java-lang-classcastexception-on-android-during-startup/18173694#comment22004388_15510420):

> I'm not sure that it matters but getApplicationContext() is also an
>   abstract method in Context  which Activity inherits. Perhaps rename
>   your method getApplicationContext() and your interface App; lets face
>   it the nomenclature of your App class could be more descriptive.